# mysql query in between dates not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following mysql table:

```
tasks:
=====================
tid
status
desc
duedate
```

And i have the following records in that table:

```
records
===========================
1
active
Test description
08/15/2014

2
active
Another description
08/31/204
```

I am trying to get the days that there is a task for, in that particular month. I have the following query but when i run it it gets both records but "day" is null on both of them for some reason. Can someone please help me with this.

```
MYSQL QUERY
====================
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(due_date,'%d') AS day FROM tasks WHERE due_date BETWEEN '08/01/2014' AND '08/31/2014'
```

Comment: Is your `duedate` column of the data type VARCHAR?

Comment: yes it is, but i tried it with the date column as well, and the result is 00 instead of null

Comment: mysql's date-as-string format is `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`. it has NO idea what your `/08/01/...` business is, therefore it won't treat them as anything other than some random strings.

Comment: thank you for that, i didn't know which format it prefers it to be stored in, but once i fixed it, it now works, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
 SELECT DAY(due_date) AS day 
   FROM tasks 
  WHERE due_date >= '2014-08' 
    AND due_date < '2014-09';
```

`DAY()` is a better function for what you want and I prefer using `>=` and  `<` than `BETWEEN` for date comparisons, as it allows you to specify precise ranges more easily. Here, for example, you don't need to know the number of days in the month.

I have also used the default date format, which is preferable. If you need the, in my opinion, cray American date format, use `DATE_FORMAT()` in your `SELECT`.

This will only work with `DATE`, `DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP` columns, which is how your `due_date` should be stored, preferably `DATE`.

**UPDATE**

To convert the `VARCHAR` column to `DATE` run:

```
UPDATE tasks SET due_date=STR_TO_DATE(due_date,'%m/%d/%Y')
```

Then change the type. Also remember to change your `INSERT` statements to use the default format.

Answer (score 2):

You've got to convert those "date" strings to proper date values with [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date):

```
SELECT 
   DAY(STR_TO_DATE(due_date,'%m/%d/%Y')) AS day 
FROM tasks 
WHERE 
  STR_TO_DATE(due_date, '%m/%d/%Y') 
  BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('08/01/2014' '%m/%d/%Y') 
  AND STR_TO_DATE('08/31/2014', '%m/%d/%Y')
```

else you're comparing strings instead.

**Note:**

It would be better to use a proper DATE or DATETIME column instead.
With the current VARCHAR format MySQL is unable to use indexes. That's very bad for performance.

You can convert your data by adding another column to your table:

```
ALTER TABLE tasks
ADD COLUMN new_due_date DATE;
```

Then you use an UPDATE statement to fill this new column

```
UPDATE tasks
SET new_due_date = STR_TO_DATE(due_date, '%m/%d/%Y');
```

If you don't need your old column anymore then you can delete this column and modify the new column to have the name of the old one. Then you will have your table with all your data in a DATE column.

Comment: It is a good advice, but it is better to use a correct DATE type.

Comment: I tried to change the column to date but then the result just gives me 00 for both records

Comment: You can't simply change the data type to date, you've got to convert those existing values with STR_TO_DATE to a new column. And you've got to modify your INSERT statements too.

Comment: @VMai you can do it with the existing column, remember it's a `VARCHAR`, see my answer. Good point about the `INSERT`s though.